# Adding new input field doesn't update the value of existing ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's how it's supposed to work. By default there are two sets of input fields where the percentage fields have a value of 50% each. Now whenever a new input field is added, the percentage field value should be divided between all of them, for example, if there are 3 sets then percentage fields should have 33.33% each. If there are 4 then 25% each. Now this part works perfectly fine.

Now I'm trying to add more features on top of it. I'll just explain the features in brief and the problem associated with it.

1. When a user clicks on `percentage input field`, the previous value disappears and the user types a new percentage value and it gets divided between the two input fields. But the issue with this is it adds two `"%"` signs at the end of the value which the user just typed in.
2. The second issue is, suppose the user types in a new percentage value in the first or second `percentage field` and then adds a new `input field` through `Add Field` button, the percentages doesn't divide between all the input values. The new `input field` doesn't take into consideration the new `percentage value`. One reason I could think of is the `percInput` variable doesn't get updated somehow.
3. The third issue is similar to the second one. If the user adds a new `input field` first and then types in a `percentage value` in that new `input field`, then percentage values are not divided at all. This could also be because of `percInput` variable not being updated. Another issue associated with this is, clicking on the new percentage input field doesn't remove the previous value, like it does on the default fields.
4. This is a weird one. If the user clicks on the percentage input field but doesn't adds a value and moves on to adding a new field, then the percentage values just divide between all of them.

All of these issues are somewhat related to each other and I have feeling a that they are all because of one variable, which is, `percInput`. I guess it doesn't get updated when new input fields are added. Previously I used `calculatePercentage` function to update the `percInput` variable, where it worked. But it doesn't work when I tried to use it in the situations above.

Here's the code I tried so far:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const span = document.querySelector("span");
const addBtn = document.querySelector("#addField");
const html = `
    <div class="url-pair">
        <input type="url" placeholder="3">
        <input type="text" class="perc">
        <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
`;

// percentage variable and percentage calculation for the first time
let percInput = document.querySelectorAll('.urls-container .perc');
let percentage = (100 / percInput.length).toFixed(0).toString() + "%";

percInput.forEach((item) => {
    item.setAttribute("value", percentage);
});

const removeField = (e) => {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('delete-btn')) return;
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    calculatePercentage(); 
}

// percentage input variable update and percentage calculation
const calculatePercentage = () => {
    percInput = document.querySelectorAll('.urls-container .perc');
    percentage = (100 / percInput.length).toFixed(0).toString() + "%";

    percInput.forEach((item) => {
        item.setAttribute("value", percentage);
    });
}

// remove a field
form.addEventListener('click', removeField);

// add input field
addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    span.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", html);
    calculatePercentage(); 
});


const percInputChange = function() {
    let val = this.value,
    $allInputs = $(percInput);

    if(val > 100) {
        $allInputs.val((100 / $allInputs.length) + "%");
        calculatePercentage();
    }else {
        $(percInput).not(this).val( (100 - val) / ($allInputs.length - 1) + "%");

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.value = this.value + "%";
        }, 500);

        calculatePercentage();

        return;
    }
};

// event listener when user types in a new percentage value
$( percInput ).on('keyup', percInputChange);

// event listener to hide previous input value
$( percInput ).focus(function() {
    this.value = "";
});

// event listener to divide the percetange values when the user clicks away
$( percInput ).blur(function() {
    if(this.value === ""){
        percInput.forEach(item => {
            item.value = ( 100 / percInput.length ).toFixed(0).toString() + "%";
            return;
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" placeholder="1">
      <input type="text" class="perc">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" placeholder="2">
      <input type="text" class="perc">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

I know this post is a weird one with so many problems. But please bear with me as I am still learning and I won't be able to learn if I don't push myself into these complex coding problems and get stuck. I've spent the whole day yesterday trying different methods based on the knowledge I have. The post would be really big if I put all the methods I tried. So please bear with me. Please help a fellow coder in need. Thanks

PS. I used jQuery and JS together which is not the right thing to do. But I will refactor and change them once I fix the issues.
PS.

Comment: The first issue is because of the keyup event. If you enter a 1 digit number, it will be one '%' if you enter a 2 digit number, you'll get %% and so on. In order to fix this, you can switch it from 'keyup' to a 'change' event. I'll take a look at the other points as well

Comment: 2nd and 3rd issues are because the page is not re-rendered after you change the value attribute, changing item.setAttribute("value", percentage); with item.value = percentage will rerender the input fields when changed, but you.ll find out you have other issues as well.

Comment: For 2nd and 3rd issues, can I put item.value = percentage where its needed? Like not everywhere.

Comment: I don't know for sure, you may give it a try. Also, if you add 4 or more fields, the index (left column) doesn't get updated anymore. If you want to try to start it all over again I can suggest the following approach: you can have an array with the rows: at first there will be only 2 elements in the array - with a value of 50. you cna have a function that adds an element in the array and recalculates all the other values. and another function that iterates through the array and display the input fields (in the left column you'll have the index and in the right you'll have the value)

Comment: Oh no that's not the index. It's the placeholder. Sorry about that. But man this thing got really complicated. And the approach you mentioned. I havent understood the last function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what exactly you want to achieve with your script. But I had a go at making a fresh start by removing redundant bits. The following snippet will allow you to add or remove input lines and it will adjust the percentages accordingly.

Maybe you can specifiy *how* you want the script to react on any user input?

```js
// add flields:
function addfields(){
   let all=$('.urls-container'), r=$('div:last',all).clone(),
       url=r.find('input[type=url]')[0];
   url.placeholder=+url.placeholder+1;
   $('.perc',r).removeAttr('data-manual');
   all.append(r); calcperc();
 }
// even distribution:
function calcperc(){
  let fix=$('.perc[data-manual]'),sum=0;
  fix.each(function(){sum+=parseFloat(this.value)});
  let rest= $('.perc').not(fix);
  rest.val(((100-sum)/rest.length).toFixed(2)+'%')
}

// manual distribution:
function recalc(){let inps=$('.perc'),cur=parseFloat(this.value);
 if (inps.length>1){
  this.value=cur.toFixed(2)+'%'; this.dataset.manual=1;
  calcperc();
} else this.value="100%"
}
// delegated event management:
$('form')
 .on('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault()}) // de-activate submit for testing
 .on('change','.perc',recalc)
 .on('click','.delete-btn',function(){$(this).parent().remove();calcperc()})
 .on('click','#addField',addfields);
 
 // initial distribution:
 calcperc();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="POST">

  <div class="urls-container">
    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" placeholder="1">
      <input type="text" class="perc">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <div class="url-pair">
      <input type="url" placeholder="2">
      <input type="text" class="perc">
      <button class="delete-btn" type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>

    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="addField">Add Field</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

My curent version of `recalc()` allows you to overwrite *one* of the percentage values. All other values will then be adjusted, so the total is 100% again.

Please also note that in my version the `recalc()` gets fired on the `input` event and not the `keyup` event, otherwise the action of adding the percentage sign would seriously interfere with any input attempt by the user.

**Edit**
The lastet edit involves "marking" manually changed percentages with a `data-manual` attribute in the input field. This will protect that field from future recalculations. The remaining percentages will be distributed evenly among the non-fixed fields.

Comment: Hi there. The thing you did, I had it working. This is not the issue. Let me explain it to you according to the issues. 1. Run the snippet and click on a percentage input value and change its value. There will be an extra % showing up at the end. I want to fix that. 
2. If you change the value of the percentage and then add a new field, percentage doesnt divide to all the fields. I want to divide to all the fields, that is, suppose you input 40% to the first field and then add a new field, then automatically 60% will divided to the next two. Like 30% to each.

Comment: Can you check again please? My `recalc` function should now do that.

Comment: Please check number 2 in my last comment. It doesn't divide the remaining percentages to the other fields. It should divide to the remaining fields except the percentage on the one the user typed in.

Comment: It does divide it *once*, during the `recalc()` call, i.e. when a user enters a new percentage value. But when you add another field, the distribution will be evened out again. Do you want to *keep* the manally entered "imbalance" when adding a new input field? If I understood your comment correctly, then you want *any entered value* to stay unaltered, whenever new fields are aded?

Comment: Man you're really good in JS and jQuery. And I want it to divide the remaining percentage to the rest of the fields. Is that possible? And another problem regarding the first issue is, When the user clicks on a input to change then the field will empty automatically. And after the user types a new percentage then the input value to all the fields will update automatically. Right now I have to click outside to update the division.

Comment: Yes yes yes. entered value to be unaltered

Comment: and not have to click outside to have to update the values. Right now I have to click outside

Comment: oh wait, if I use keyup in your code then it works. I dont have to click outside.

Comment: Further edit: Now the unaltered values stay put - even after adding new fields ...

Comment: Okay I fixed the focus issue in your code. It disappears when the input is clicked on. Also the keyup event fixed the issue of clicking outside. But another issue arose. The calculation is super fast. like if I want to press 20 and press 2 first then already makes the calculation.

Comment: Please check now - I adjusted my `addfields()`-function too. And `recalc()' should definitely fire at `input`, i. e. when focus is taken away from the input field in question. And you don't need to "click outside" - just press the tab key instead!

Comment: Sorry - I just used the wrong word in "For that reason I replaced keyup with input" - I meant of course: "For that reason I replaced keyup with **change**!!!"

Comment: hey I want to use keyup event but as it calculates right away, can I use a debounce function and make it delay a bit?

Comment: I think it will always cause problems as long as you are adding a "%" sign at the end. But maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885513/2610061 ?

Comment: Okay if I use the percentage sign as the one in that post, do I have to change a lot of your code to use the debounce function?

Comment: If you go for the solution in the link you will have to change a "bit" but you can definitely do *without* any "debounce function"! (I am running out of time now and hope that you can do something with the code provided so far ...)

Comment: hey mate, sorry to bother you again, but I wanted to know something. Can't I use variables instead of using classes directly? For example, in ```calcperc``` or ```recalc``` function, you used ```'.perc'```to choose the element, but if I make a variable like ```const percInput = document.querySelector('form .urls-container .url-pair .perc');``` and put ```percInput``` in ```calcperc```  fn, your code breaks. Nothing works. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Please note that I used the **jQuery** object `$('.perc')` that works on *all* DOM elements having class `perc` while the "Vanilla" version `document.querySelector('.perc')` will only return the *first* encountered DOM element with class 'perc'. If you want to work with the Vanilla JS version you will have to do explicit looping on collections of DOM elements you might be getting from `document.quersSelectorAll()`. jQuery on the other hand will implicitly "loop", whenever multiple elements are selected.

Comment: I know, jQuery-bashing is kind of fashionable but as you have it included in your page anyway it can save you tons of work (and code) *if* you get into the jQuery-mode of doing things. Write less - do more!

Comment: Yeah. I understood now. Thank you so much. You're like the jQuery King here in SO. Good job mate. Hope I can code like you some day.